# Inverse Matrix Another method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Is there another method (involving determinants) for finding the inverse of a matrix than making the matrix equal to what it is supposed to look like in reduced row echelon form? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in the [adjugate formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Inverses) for a matrix inverse.

Comment: You can use cramer's rule. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse of matrix (suppose A)

$$A^{-1} =\frac{ adjoint(A)}{det(A)}$$

*$A^{-1}$ Exist iff $det(A)≠0$

Answer (score 1):

For a $(2\times2)$-matrix you may use the following formula:

$$\frac{1}{ad-bc}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} 
d & -b \\
-c & a \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$